# SpecialServiceRQ: NO VALID SEGMENTS FOUND - CHECK ITINERARY

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to make a SpecialServiceRQ for a PNR being created for itinerary LON-NYC

```
<SpecialServiceRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.0.2">
    <SpecialServiceInfo>
        <Service SSR_Code="INFT" SegmentNumber="1">
        <Text>GOMEZ/BEBE/23OCT18-1.1</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="INFT" SegmentNumber="2">
        <Text>GOMEZ/BEBE/23OCT18-1.1</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="FOID">
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <Text>PPAAC385679</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="DOCO">
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <Text>/K/12547</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="DOCS">
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <Text>DB/01JUN77/M/GOMEZ/DIEGO</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="FOID">
        <PersonName NameNumber="2.1"/>
        <Text>PPAAC981274</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="DOCS">
        <PersonName NameNumber="2.1"/>
        <Text>DB/23NOV15/M/GOMEZ/NINO</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="DOCO">
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <Text>/R/7876533////I</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
        <Service SSR_Code="DOCS">
        <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
        <Text>DB/23OCT18/FI/GOMEZ/BEBE</Text>
        <VendorPrefs>
            <Airline Hosted="false"/>
        </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
    </SpecialServiceInfo>
</SpecialServiceRQ>
```

But I get

```
<SpecialServiceRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.0.2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
    <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
    <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-01-27T11:46:35-06:00">
    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        <stl:Message>.NO VALID SEGMENTS FOUND - CHECK ITINERARY.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</stl:Message>
        <stl:Message>3FOID/PPAAC385679-1.1</stl:Message>
        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    </stl:Error>
    </stl:ApplicationResults>
</SpecialServiceRS>
```

**The same request works for itineraries like EZE-LIM**

Am I missing something? The itinerary involves United States, so I include de TSA Secure Flight mandatory DOCS with names, DOB and gender information, as seen on the request I'm sending to Sabre WS

Answer (score 0):

From the schema [SpecialServiceLLSRQ_v2.3.0](http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/SpecialServiceLLSRQ_v2.3.0_Design.xml) - I see that for SSR Docs you need to use  "AdvancePassenger" or "SecureFlight"

**Please note that it is no longer possible to specify SSR_Code="DOC*", please utilize either "AdvancePassenger" or "SecureFlight" to send document SSRs.**

```xml
<SpecialServiceRQ Version="2.3.0">
    <SpecialServiceInfo>
        <!-- Optional -->
        <!-- Repeat Factor=0-99 -->
        <!-- "SegmentNumber" is used to specify an itinerary segment to associate the SSR to. -->
        <!-- "SSR_Code" is used to specify an SSR code. -->
        <!--
    Please note that it is no longer possible to specify SSR_Code="DOC*", please utilize either "AdvancePassenger" or "SecureFlight" to send document SSRs.
    -->
        <!-- If SSR_Code="OSI" @SegmentNumber cannot be utilized. -->
        <!-- Equivalent Sabre host command: 4WCHR2-3.1 -->
        <Service SegmentNumber="2" SSR_Code="WCHR">
            <!-- Optional, BUT some SSRCodes require a name number. -->
            <!-- Repeat Factor=0 -->
            <!-- "Number" is used to specify a passenger name number. -->
            <!-- Equivalent Sabre host command: 4WCHR2-3.1 -->
            <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" />
            <!-- Optional, BUT many SSRCodes RQs require text. -->
            <!-- Repeat Factor=0 -->
            <!-- "Text" is used to specify miscellaneous free text information. -->
            <!-- Equivalent Sabre host command: 3OSI YY TEST -->
            <Text>TEST</Text>
            <!-- Optional -->
            <!-- Repeat Factor=0 -->
            <VendorPrefs>
                <!-- Mandatory -->
                <!-- Repeat Factor=0 -->
                <!--
    "Code" is only applicable to the "OSI" SSRCode, and is used to specify the airline that the SSR needs to be sent to.
    -->
                <!-- "Hosted" is used to specify if the request is based upon a hosted or a non-hosted carrier. -->
                <!--
    For Travel Network-based customers "HostedCarrier" can be set to "false" unless the message is being sent to AA.
    -->
                <!--
    For SabreSonic RES-based customers "HostedCarrier" should be set to "true" when communicating internally, and omitted when sending to any other carrier.
    -->
                <!-- Hosted="false" example: 3WCHR2-3.1 -->
                <!-- Hosted"true" example: 4WCHR2-3.1 -->
                <!-- Code example: 3OSI YY TEST -->
                <Airline Code="YY" Hosted="true" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </Service>
    </SpecialServiceInfo>
</SpecialServiceRQ>
```

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.2, which doesn't have that restriction:
view-source:http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/SpecialServiceLLSRQ_v2.0.2_Design.xml

Comment: Yes, you should send the data under SecureFlight element

Answer (score 0):

Also, the error is returned after the 3FOID/PPAAC385679-1.1 format. Is this applicable to your itinerary? All segments require FOID data, and are those segments AA or other airline?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is regarding the TSA required information, it means you have to send the APIS

```
    APIS - ADVANCE PASSENGER INFORMATION SYSTEM
    When travelling to certain countries, the respective local government may request for the
    detailed information of the passenger. For example, the U.S. and Canadian Transportation
    Security Administration (TSA) requires all airlines to provide the passport information, Date of
    birth, VISA info, destination or residential addresses of all passengers travelling to the United
    States.
    Some airlines require passenger information like passport number as the form of identification at
    check-in.
```

**For send Advance Passenger Information (APIS) for passport document for multiple segments.**

```
Send Advance Passenger Information (APIS) for passport document.
Equivalent Sabre host command: 3DOCSA/P/US/1234567890/US/02DEC1960/M/26MAY2029/SIMPSON/HOMER/JAY-1.1
```

```
<SpecialServiceRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.3.0">
    <SpecialServiceInfo>
        <AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="A">
            <Document ExpirationDate="2029-05-26" Number="1234567890" Type="P">
                <IssueCountry>US</IssueCountry>
                <NationalityCountry>US</NationalityCountry>
            </Document>
            <PersonName DateOfBirth="1960-12-02" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                <GivenName>Homer</GivenName>
                <MiddleName>Jay</MiddleName>
                <Surname>Simpson</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Hosted="false"/>
            </VendorPrefs>
        </AdvancePassenger>
    </SpecialServiceInfo>
</SpecialServiceRQ>
```

For send Advance Passenger Information (APIS) for passport document for multiple segments you should use this format in *SegmentNumber* property

```
<AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="1,2">
```